# PHP DateTime::format with html character entities

Tags: php, html, datetime, html-entities

I'm writing dates to the DOM from a MySQL database that are being formatted by PHP's DateTime class (my server's running PHP 5.5.14) like this

`$start_date->format('M. d, Y');`

However, the year is wrapping to a new line when it reaches the end of the div. I wish I could insert a non-breaking space like this:

`$start_date->format('M.&nbsp;d,&nbsp;Y');`

But the class thinks think the n and s are format characters, and spits out this gibberish: *Mar.&3b30p;27,&3b30p;2015*

Could I escape those characters? Or would I have to make a function that replaces the spaces with html character entities after the date has been formatted?

Comment: So you gave up or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the ones that are format characters:

```
'M.&\n\b\s\p;d,&\n\b\s\p;Y'
```

I just escaped them all instead of looking up which ones were necessary to be escaped. It's also easier to see that they are not meant as a part of the format if they are escaped.

This is only going to work in the single-quoted string as `\n` will be a newline in double-quoted.

Comment: Sorry, got caught up in other projects. I like just escaping all character. It is more readable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent this by escaping `n` and `s` with a preceding backslash.

This line of code should work for you:

```
$start_date->format('M.&\nb\sp;d,&\nb\sp;Y');
```

This will output: `Mar. 27, 2015`

A nice example of date formatting: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#example-2501

Answer (score 0):

Or you can

```
<?php echo $start_date->format('M.'); ?>
&nbsp;
<?php echo $start_date->format('d,'); ?>
&nbsp;
<?php echo $start_date->format('Y'); ?>
```